# Is there documentation for Lightning:... components that goes beyond the Component Reference pages?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, slds, documentation

There are now many `lightning:...` components listed in the Lightning Components Developer Guide [Component Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref.htm) that generate SLDS markup and standard icons. This is good news, potentially making consistent SLDS styling much less tedious to achieve.

I am wondering if there is any Salesforce or 3rd party documentation that goes further such as:

- a visual reference i.e. what each component looks like in a page
- examples of standard ways to compose these components into common layouts

Comment: [This page](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/getting-started/) has visual examples and usage guidance. Doesn't seem to be what you're looking for though, since it doesn't reference those components specifically.

Comment: very much needed!!! add an idea for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of not too long ago (2018)

the [component-library overview](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/overview/components)  seems to do just that, including:

- code blueprint with different modalities (like the SLDS Doc)
- a Visual Representation
- the Reference Doc
- Searchable interface with filters for different interfaces

[image]

Forgot to mention -> the new Auradocs, now adopt the same format as the above component documentation, however, the URL is now:

> [https://`DOMAIN`.lightning.force.com/docs/component-library/overview/components](https://DOMAIN.lightning.force.com/docs/component-library/overview/components)

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [Lightning Design System](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/) website for previews. They have linked directly to each of these reference points in every 'lightning:' pages. The exact wording used would be something on the lines of, 'This component inherits styling from ____ in the Lightning Design System.'

Lightning:card for example can be previewed [here](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/cards/).

Comment: Thanks, I should have said in the question that I am familiar with that web site. Was hoping for something more like a component cheat sheet.

Comment: Ah yes, I get it @KeithC even I get sick of back and forths very often. Should put it as a Salesforce Idea for now I think